# Convert Informix cursor to MSSQL Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, informix

I have a cursor in Informix database which is part of a function, I would like to convert that into a cursor in MS-SQL.

Below is the code:

```
DECLARE select distinct agentname, agentloginid 
           from selected_agents

            call;
   OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID;
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN getAgentLogActivity(@l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID, @p_startTime, @p_endTime);
           insert into final_result(Agent_Name, Agent_Login_ID, op1, Login_Time, op2, 
                           Logout_Time, Logout_Reason_Code, Logon_Duration)
            select @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID, op1, logintime, op2, logouttime, reasoncode, duration
                from temp_login_logout;
   FETCH cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID;
   end
   CLOSE cur;
   DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Here in this case I am finding issues with Declare statement. I know I have to write this in the way below.

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
   SELECT DISTINCT agentname, agentloginid 
           from selected_agents
   OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID;
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN getAgentLogActivity(@l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID, @p_startTime, @p_endTime);
           insert into final_result(Agent_Name, Agent_Login_ID, op1, Login_Time, op2, 
                           Logout_Time, Logout_Reason_Code, Logon_Duration)
            select @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID, op1, logintime, op2, logouttime, reasoncode, duration
                from temp_login_logout;
   FETCH cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID;
   end
   CLOSE cur;
   DEALLOCATE cur;
```

> UPDATED - selected_agents declaration

```
DECLARE @selected_agents TABLE (
        agentloginid NVARCHAR(50), 
        agentname NVARCHAR(50),
        agentID INT,
        profileid INT,
        resourcegroupid int,
        dateinactive datetime,
        --filter boolean default 'f',
        rsmid INT,
        teamid INT
    );
```

Now here ***selected_agents*** is a temp table which I have created in the function.

The error what it says is that  agentname, agentloginid is not declared. Which I have already declared btw.

Can someone help me with how can i correct it.

Comment: You need to fetch next but where did you declare these variables?

Comment: I have created a temp table before this cursor declaration.

This cursor and temp table is part of a function that I have.

Comment: Mind posting that code? Temp table isn't the same as variables. Thanks!

Comment: You need to change from selected_agents to from @selected_agents. Also where is the declaration for `@l_AgentName and @l_AgentLoginID`. Just a side note, #trmpTable is a temporary table while `@table` is a table variable which only exists for the life of the transaction. Temp tables are accessible until they are dropped or the connection is closed.

Comment: This is how I have declared @l_AgentName and @l_AgentLoginID:          
`DECLARE @l_AgentName NVARCHAR(50), @l_AgentLoginID NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @l_AgentExtension NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @l_op1 NVARCHAR(1), @l_op2 NVARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @l_LoginTime DATETIME2(3), @l_LogoutTime DATETIME2(3), @l_latestSynchedTime DATETIME2(3);
    DECLARE @l_LogoutReasonCode SMALLINT, @l_selType SMALLINT;
    DECLARE @l_LogonDuration INT, @l_resCount INT, @l_op INT;
    declare @l_selValue varchar(4000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be 100% a solution, but it has a lot of comments to get you started. Feel free to comment to let me know where you are still having problems.

```
DECLARE @selected_agents TABLE (
        agentloginid NVARCHAR(50), 
        agentname NVARCHAR(50),
        agentID INT,
        profileid INT,
        resourcegroupid int,
        dateinactive datetime,
        --filter boolean default 'f',
        rsmid INT,
        teamid INT
    );


/*
Do something here to insert data into @selected_agents
*/

DECLARE @l_AgentName NVARCHAR(50), @l_AgentLoginID NVARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE @l_AgentExtension NVARCHAR(50); 
DECLARE @l_op1 NVARCHAR(1), @l_op2 NVARCHAR(1); 
DECLARE @l_LoginTime DATETIME2(3), @l_LogoutTime DATETIME2(3), @l_latestSynchedTime DATETIME2(3); 
DECLARE @l_LogoutReasonCode SMALLINT, @l_selType SMALLINT;
DECLARE @l_LogonDuration INT, @l_resCount INT, @l_op INT; 
DECLARE @l_selValue varchar(4000);

--Added @ in front of the table name, since it is a table variable you need the @.
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT agentname, agentloginid 
    from @selected_agents

OPEN cur

--Here we added NEXT FROM to make the syntax correct
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

    --Here you seem to be attempting to call a function to potentially set your variables, but this likley isn't happening
    --In another window, try this function and then select the values of your variables to make sure they are being set
    getAgentLogActivity(@l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID, @p_startTime, @p_endTime);

    insert into final_result(Agent_Name, Agent_Login_ID, op1, Login_Time, op2,Logout_Time, Logout_Reason_Code, Logon_Duration)
    select 
        @l_AgentName, 
        @l_AgentLoginID, 
        op1, 
        logintime, 
        op2, 
        logouttime, 
        reasoncode, 
        duration
    from 
        temp_login_logout;

--Here we added NEXT FROM to make the syntax correct
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @l_AgentName, @l_AgentLoginID; t

END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Comment: Sorry @scsimon, I figured it out by ur last comment. By putting @ to the declaration and it worked

Comment: Thanks for circling back for closure... so this was a solution. Glad to know that.

Comment: I didnt saw this solution earlier. So did not know

Comment: No problem, now you do know and that's what is important.