# Execute procedure by passing input to procedure from function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

Just to give you a background here, what I am doing is I have Informix database and I am converting procedures and functions in Informix to SQL Server procedures and functions. I have already converted the code and I want to execute that.

Now, the procedure has input parameters and those input parameters come from a function. Below you have snapshot of procedure and function declaration.

> Function Declaration

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_agent_log_activity (@p_startTime DATETIME,
                                       @p_endTime DATETIME,
                                       @p_sortBy int = 0,
                                       @p_resGroupList VARCHAR(4000) = 'NULL',
                                       @p_agentList VARCHAR(4000) = 'NULL',
                                       @p_skillList VARCHAR(4000) = 'NULL',
                                       @p_teamList VARCHAR(4000) = 'NULL')
RETURNS @sp_agent_log_activity_tab TABLE ( Agent_Name NVARCHAR(50),
          Agent_Login_ID NVARCHAR(50),
          Agent_Extension NVARCHAR(50),
          op1 NVARCHAR(1),
          Login_Time DATETIME2(3),
          op2 NVARCHAR(1),
          Logout_Time DATETIME2(3),
          Logout_Reason_Code SMALLINT,
          Logon_Duration INT,
          latestSynchedTime DATETIME2(3))
```

> Procedure Declaration

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAgentLogActivity @p_agentname NVARCHAR(50),
                @p_agentloginid NVARCHAR(50), 
                @p_startTime DATETIME,
                @p_endTime DATETIME             
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @l_event_login SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_event_logout SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_eventtype SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_reasoncode SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_agentid INT
    DECLARE @l_eventdatetime DATETIME
    DECLARE @l_filter BIT
    DECLARE @l_mineventdatetime DATETIME
    DECLARE @l_maxeventdatetime DATETIME
    DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var1 CURSOR
```

Also for reference I have procedure and function below on github.
[Function and Procedure Complete code](https://github.com/abdulquadirshaikh/Infomix-to-SQL-Server-Conversion)

I will be glad if someone could just guide me how I can input parameter to procedure from function.

Comment: No comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730554/convert-informix-cursor-to-mssql-cursor/42748470#42748470)? At least this one give **more** details than your last.

Comment: Google [Table Type Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @scsimon this is a different question.

Comment: @M.Ali can u please tell me how it will be in my case above

Comment: @AbdulquadirShaikh if you would have read the documentation your wont be asking me to explain it.

Comment: @M.Ali I did read the documentation. But here I already have function and procedure created and I want to assign what function is returning to the procedures input. And thats not what my understanding is with what document is saying. Correct me if I wrong. And I am new to this so confused a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well lets suppose you have read the documentation carefully now you are ready to implement it.

Prior to SQL Server 2008, for stored procedures we could only create parameters of default data types (Int, Varchar, Bit etc) or user-defined types based on default system data types.

In 2008 SQL server introduced the user define `table type`. Basically a data type which represents a tables structure.

For Example prior to 2008 we could only create user-defined types which a base type of default sql server data type. something like...

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestTypeName]  --<-- Name of the data type  
FROM VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ;       --<--  VARCHAR(15) is the base data type
```

In SQL Server 2008 we were able to create data types which represented a structure of a table something like....

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestTableTypeName]   --<-- Name of the data type 
AS TABLE   
    ( Column1 VARCHAR(50)               --<-- a Table as a base data type
    , Column2 INT );  
GO
```

Now since we could create these Table-types, which means we could also define a variable of this type. Just like you would declare a variable of INT or any other default data type.

```
DECLARE @T AS [dbo].[TestTableTypeName];
```

Now the variable `@T` is a table variable and has the same table structure as defined for the table type `[dbo].[TestTableTypeName]`.

Now because we can declare a variable of `[dbo].[TestTableTypeName]` type we can also make a procedure's input variable of this type.

Something like.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myTestProc
 @Var1  INT 
,@T  AS [dbo].[TestTableTypeName] READONLY 
AS
.......
```

The Stored procedure `myTestProc` has an input variable `@T` of a table type `[dbo].[TestTableTypeName]` which means I can pass a table to this procedure as a parameter.

Mind you this table-type parameter is read-only if I need to make any changes to the passed table, I would need to put data into another table variable of temp table and then make changes to the data so on and so forth.

For your case you need to create a Table type which represents the table structure same as the table being returned by the function. Something like....

**Table Type**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[sp_agent_log_activity_tab]   
AS TABLE (  
Agent_Name      NVARCHAR(50),
Agent_Login_ID  NVARCHAR(50),
Agent_Extension NVARCHAR(50),
op1             NVARCHAR(1),
Login_Time      DATETIME2(3),
op2             NVARCHAR(1),
Logout_Time     DATETIME2(3),
Logout_Reason_Code SMALLINT,
Logon_Duration  INT,
latestSynchedTime DATETIME2(3)) 
GO
```

Now Make your procedure to have an input parameter of this type.

**SP Definition**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAgentLogActivity 
  @T AS [dbo].[sp_agent_log_activity_tab] READONLY 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @l_event_login SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_event_logout SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_eventtype SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_reasoncode SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_agentid INT
```

Now change rest of the procedure definition to handle this table type parameter.

**Execution**

Once all above is done then you would execute the procedure something like.....

```
Declare @T AS [dbo].[sp_agent_log_activity_tab];

INSERT INTO @t 
SELECT ColumnNames....
FROM sp_agent_log_activity (@param1 , @param2, @Param3....)

EXEC getAgentLogActivity @T =  @T
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood what I have to do. I just want to for @param's I have to include the column the function is returning. if yes then I am getting an error with invalid column name for the column I am including like Agent_Name, Agent_Login_Id. Also I am getting errors as "too many argument specified" Thanks